# C++ how to access value of inherited and overridden attribute of base class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I try to do something like this:

```
class A{
public:
    A(){number = 1;}
    int number;
};
class B : public A{
public:
    B(){number = 2;}
};

class Base {
public:
    Base() {myAttribute = new A();}
    int returnAttrNumber(){return myAttribute->number;}
    A *myAttribute;
};

class Inherited : public Base{
public:
    Inherited(){myAttribute = new B();}
    B *myAttribute;
};


int main()
{
    Inherited *i = new Inherited();
    std::cout << i->returnAttrNumber(); // outputs 1, because it gets the A not the B. I want it to output 2, to get the B object in returnAttrNumber()
}
```

So, class Base holds an object A. Inherited holds an A-derived object B. And I try to call a method on the base class, but I want it to cast down in the hirarchy of the corresponding Object as far as possible (**without static_cast or dynamic_cast**) and then take the B object, not A and do stuff (returning it's number in in this case)

Is there a way to do that downcasting from a base class in C++ without big difficulties?
Thanks for answers!

Comment: Please post some realistic code. Details matter.

Comment: "this should change the value stored in Inherited, not in Base" there is only one member that can change its value. Please dont use fantasy code. This has just too much syntax errors that distract from the actual question

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I fixed it, that works now

Comment: You only have one int variable in the entire program...

Comment: And now it would work if you only spelled `myAttribure` consistently. And put the last code inside a function.

Comment: Yes, I guess I missed the problematic part at the end of the program, I'm sorry!

Comment: `class Base{  virtual int get_myAttribute()=0; [...]};`  `class Derived{ int myAttribute=10;   int get_myAttribute() override {return myAttribute;}};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as rioki said,

> Base and Inherited have *different* variables

This is because I redeclared MyAttribute as a B in Inherited. This was the mistake. I thought, when I declare it with the same name, it will be the same variable, that's wrong.
So the whole solution for this is to uncomment this one line in Inherited. Working code:

```
class A{
public:
    A(){number = 1;}
    int number;
};
class B : public A{
public:
    B(){number = 2;}
};

class Base {
public:
    Base() {myAttribute = new A();}
    int returnAttrNumber(){return myAttribute->number;}
    A *myAttribute;
};

class Inherited : public Base{
public:
    Inherited(){myAttribute = new B();}
    //B *myAttribute;
};


int main()
{
    Base *i = new Inherited(); // this works, what is necessary in my case
    std::cout << i->returnAttrNumber(); // outputs 2 now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is *very* bad design. The quick answer is you can access variable from the base class via the fully qualified identifier. Take the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:    
    A()
    : var(1) {}

protected:
    int var;
};


class B : public A
{    
public:
    B()
    : var(2) {}

    int getBVar() const
    {
        return var;
    }

    int getAVar() const
    {
        return A::var;
    }

private:
    int var;
};

int main()
{    
    B b;
    std::cout << "A: " << b.getAVar() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B: " << b.getBVar() << std::endl;
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
A: 1
B: 2
```

About the down casting bit... Base and Inherited have *different* variables. You can not safely case one to the other.

Comment: Ok, Thank you! Well this would be possible, although it wouldn't be nice, because the hirarchy in my program includes many classes. This seems not to be a very specific problem to me, so I am wondering, why I can not cast down or why the object can't give a hint, which inherited type it is of (in the base class)... What exactely do you mean with very bad design? Is there a nicer way to do that (/to do that kind of parallel hirarchy like in my example)?

Comment: Because you are aliasing "myAttribute". Initially they all point to the same object, but let's imagine A changes myArrtibute to an other instance. It does not know anything about B's implementation, so it can't update that. Now both pointers are pointing to *different* objects.